# Write to text file and start at specific position

Tags: c#, .net, string

I an writing a program to create a type of file. The specifications show that I must have certain delimited factors where as strings on the same line have limits on how long they can be and the starting position of them on the line.

For instance.

I am trying to write a text file.

First line should show the string of "TEST1" which would start at the 0 position on the first line and create spaces for the total count of 10. So there would be 5 spaces after the string.

On the same line on the 11th position it would write "TEST2" which again would have the total count of 10 so there would be 5 spaces after the string.

The strings of "TEST1" and "TEST2" can change at anytime from 1-10 characters.

I have tried String.format("{0,10}" and it appears that it allows that to end at the 10th position but not what I am looking for.

This is for a FNMA file.

Comment: Use File.Seek() method to set position from where you want to begin writing

Comment: You should try `String.Format("{0,-10}", ...)`, or, better yet, use  the equivalent method of `StreamWriter`. But beware: if the string is longer than the specified width, it will overflow and misalign all the following fields.

Comment: You should probably decide to use an encoding where all characters are the same number of bytes, like ASCII or UTF-16. If you use UTF-8 then it could be unpredictable how many bytes 10 characters are going to take.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aready suggested method but you have to know that if the file is in the `UTF-8` format you need to skip the [UTF-8 BOM (header)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) that you can get with the [UTF8Encoding.GetPreamble Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getpreamble(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing the encoding constructor `true` becasue be default you wouldn't get it. For an ASCII file the offset would be 0.

```
var value = string.Format("{0,-10}", "TEST33");

FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("test.txt");

System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true);
int preamble = enc.GetPreamble().Length;
var bytes = enc.GetBytes(value);

fs.Seek(preamble, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

fs.Close();
```